# Unix time to weeks

Tags: php, unix, time

How can I easy convert a unix time to a weeks, days or months?

For example I got `604800` in unix time, which means thats 1 week, `3600` is 1 day etc.

I know this can be done using divisions, but I wonder if there is any ready-function for this.

Comment: That's not Unix time, that's just seconds. Unix time is time since January 1st, 1970 (which is usually measured in seconds, but may actually be smaller increments than that).

Comment: Uh, right :S. Sorry for that. But unix time is seconds too.

Comment: I think there is no such a function, it's not a common need and, as you said, it's easily done by computing a division..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP have nice implementation of this, look at http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/time-helper/#line-463

Answer (score 3):

From a timestamp, you can get much information using date(). For example:

```
$year = date('Y', $timestamp);
$dayOfYear = date('z', $timestamp);
$weekOfYear = date('W', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert seconds to a week number and so on use date() function